# How can i reshape this data to look like this?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Sorry if this is a bit confusing, but I need to reshape my data from the top part of my photo to the bottom. I have rows of multiple of the same ID's, however I would like to separate them out into different items instead of multiple rows of the same ID. In my photo, the bottom part does have blanks, but they would be filled in with more rows of data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Srd.png

Comment: Please post data [as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) not images, so users can easily copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_wider` function from `tidyr` package to achieve this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_wider(., names_from = CandidateID, values_from = Score)
```

here, I assume that your dataframe is called `df`. Also, as you do not provide a reproducible example (in the format described here:  [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)), I can't test this code on your real data.

So, if it is not working for you, please consider adding a reproducible example